# Gauss-Seidel iterative method not converging

Tags: systems-of-equations, linear-programming

I'm trying to solve a linear system of linear equations using the Gauss-Seidel iterative method. I'm writing c code to do it for me since I have over 349 entries to solve. In other words, I have 349 equations each with 3 unknowns so I'm calculated each unknown in 3 equation chunks.

at the end I average the weights I have calculated, so I'm not concerned with the solutions to each individual equation

the code looks like

```
  int i;
  double epsilon = .00000000001;
  double error = 1;
  double w1 = 1, w2 = 1, w3 = 1, error1, error2, error3, w1_sum = 0, w2_sum = 0, w3_sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 349; i++){
    w1 = 1;
    w2 = 1;
    w3 = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
      w1 = (pythag[i] - (adjD[i]*w2 + adjTemp[i]*w3)) / adjO[i];
      w2 = (pythag[i+1] - (adjO[i+1]*w1 + adjTemp[i+1]*w3)) / adjD[i+1];
      w3 = (pythag[i+2] - (adjO[i+2]*w1 + adjD[i+2]*w2)) / adjTemp[i+2];
    }
    w1_sum += w1;
    w2_sum += w2;
    w3_sum += w3;
  }

  double weight1 = w1_sum / 349;
  double weight2 = w2_sum / 349;
  double weight3 = w3_sum / 349;

  printf("Weight 1 = %G\n", weight1);
  printf("Weight 2 = %G\n", weight2);
  printf("Weight 3 = %G\n", weight3);
```

as I increase the size of the inner loop, w1, w2, and w3 increase instead of converging

Comment: Maybe the algorithm is numerically instable for some matrices.

Comment: hmm i suppose thats possible, any other methods you can think of that are stable?

Comment: GS doesn't always converge.  It does if the matrix is SPD or if it is strictly diagonally dominant.  Otherwise it's anyone's guess whether it converges or not. Note that for a 3x3 system you're better off using a Gaussian elimination in your internal loop.

Comment: Any reason why you don't just use some standard software, e.g. Matlab's backslash function?